# Why does the definition of a bounded function, and its negation, seem to prove contradictions?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

If I want to show that $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{x}$ is not bounded above on $(0,1]$, the way I have learnt to proceed is to assume that $f$ is bounded above, so by definition there is a number $M > 0$ such that for all $x\in (0, 1]$ we have $f(x) \leq M$, and then show that this leads to a contradiction because $\dfrac{1}{M+1}\in (0, 1]$ so there is an $x$ such that $f(x) = M+1 > M$.

But now, embarrassingly, I can't understand why if we start by assuming that $f$ is not bounded, it also seem to lead to a contradiction:
Assume $f$ is not bounded above, which means that for all numbers $M$ there is some $x\in (0, 1]$ such that $f(x) > M$. But this impossible since $f(x)$ is also a number, so by setting $M = f(x)$ the assumption is false, so $f$ must be bounded.

I have considered if the definition I am using is wrong, or If I am negating it wrong, but according to all sources I find the definition is in logical symbols
$\exists M\in \mathbb{R} \forall x \in D_f [M \geq f(x)]$
So the negation should be
$\forall M \in \mathbb{R} \exists x \in D_f [\neg(M\geq f(x))]$

But obviously I must be doing a fundamental mistake somewhere?

Comment: You can't set $M=f(x)$ because we find (or an oracle tells us) $x$ only *after* we have agreed on some potential $M$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Oh yes of course, I'm always making this mistake!

Comment: Tangentially, you might take Halsey Royden's good advice to avoid proofs by contradiction. Here, for example, "Let $M$ be an arbitrary real number. If $x = \min(1, \frac{1}{1 + |M|})$, then $0 < x \leq 1$, but $f(x) = \frac{1}{x} \geq 1 + |M| > M$. Since $M$ was arbitrary, $f$ is not bounded above on $(0, 1]$."

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang That is an interesting point! I do however really like proofs by contradiction so I will not give up on it just yet!

Comment: To summarize Royden's point (inadequately): A proof by contraposition builds a direct logical link between hypothesis and conclusion, and is relatively easy to read and evaluate. By comparison, students' proofs by contradiction tend to be longer, to meander into irrelevancies, and to go logically astray in ways difficult to find. There are separate logical and psychological issues that this comment is, unfortunately, too small to contain. Of course, you're welcome to write proofs the way you like, but "why reinforce suboptimal habits?" :)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang That seems pretty reasonable. But are there not certain situations where proof by contradiction leads to a shorter/neater or easier proof too? Besides, every theorem is not a conditional statement, like the theorem that there are infinitely many primes. Is it not a matter of knowing one's ability and the theorem's nature and evaluate the situation accordingly? If you never practice you will never get better. I find your point very interesting though, do you know where I can read more about Royden's (or anyone else's) thoughts about this matter?:)

Comment: Royden's advice comes from the preface to his _Real Analysis_. (Offhand, I can't think of a proof by contradiction that's simpler than an equivalent proof by contraposition, but that's not to say no such example exists. The infinitude of primes, incidentally, _can_ be phrased, "If $S = \{p_{1}, \dots, p_{n}\}$ is a set of primes, there exists a prime $p \not\in S$." This phrasing admits a clean contrapositive proof.)